# Oracle error ORA-12571 encountered for Select Statement

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, dbproviderfactories

I'm trying to read table data from ORACLE with Parameter binding in c#. While executing the dataAdapter I'm getting ORA-12571 exception.

Below is my code for reading multiple data at the same time.

```
public DataTable SelectFromServer(string qualifiedDBName, DataTable dataTable)        {
            try
            {
                if (this.Con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    this.OpenConnection();
                }
                DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.TableName = qualifiedDBName;
                DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(this.Con);
                using (DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand())
                {
                   
                    command.Connection = this.Con;
                    command.CommandText = this.GenerateSqlToSelect(factory,command,dataTable);
                    DbDataAdapter adapter = factory.CreateDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                    adapter.Fill(resultTable);
                    return resultTable;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                throw exc;
            }
        }
```

Below is the method where I used to generate Select Query

```
  private string GenerateSqlToSelect(DbProviderFactory factory, DbCommand command, DataTable table)
        {

            //var values1 = new List<string>();
            var SelectQuery = new StringBuilder();
            var data = table.ToArray();
            var syntax = new OracleSyntax();

            command.GetType().GetProperty("ArrayBindCount").SetValue(command, table.Rows.Count, null);
         

            for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                var names = new StringBuilder();
                var values = new StringBuilder();
                var column = table.Columns[i];

                OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter();
                parameter.ParameterName = column.ColumnName;
                parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                parameter.DbType = column.DataType.GetDbType();
                parameter.Value = data[i];
                parameter.ArrayBindSize = GetDataLength(data[i]);
                if (SelectQuery.Length > 0)
                {
                    SelectQuery.Append(" and ");
                }
                names.AppendFormat("{0}", column.ColumnName);
                values.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", syntax.ParameterPrefix, column.ColumnName);
                SelectQuery.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", names, values);
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }

            string operationString = "SELECT * FROM";
            string sqlQuery = string.Format("{0} {1} WHERE {2}", operationString,  this.FormatByQuote(syntax,table.TableName), SelectQuery);
            return sqlQuery;
        }

private int[] GetDataLength(object[] objs)
        {
            List<int> dataLengthIterator = new List<int>();
            foreach (object obj in objs)
            {
                dataLengthIterator.Add(obj.ToString().Length);
            }
            return dataLengthIterator.ToArray();
        }
```

**this.FormatByQuote()** method is nothing but getting a quoted TableName.

**Output of GenerateSqlToSelect() method is**

SELECT * FROM "CUSTOMER_MASTER" WHERE USER_ID= :USER_ID and LINE_NUMBER = :LINE_NUMBER

**The Query is generating based upon the DataTable input**

Tried multiple workarounds but could not get the reason why the exception is occurring.

Comment: Did you observe the final query generated by your code and try to run it directly against the database? Does it work?

Comment: Searching the web says this could be caused by lots of reasons.  Best to trace.  See following page to setup a trace : http://juliandyke.com/Diagnostics/Trace/NetTrace.php

Comment: What is output of "GenerateSqlToSelect" function? Can you paste that query here? Chances  are there that something is wrong in that SQL query, which is resulting in this exception.

Comment: @AbhayDesai  The Output of the GenerateSqlToSelect is SELECT * FROM "CUSTOMER_MASTER" WHERE USER_ID= :USER_ID and LINE_NUMBER = :LINE_NUMBER

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, I have validated the query in database it is working

Comment: @jdweng I will try with your link

Comment: Which driver are you using?  Most people with oracle use the ODBC driver.  See following for list of drivers : https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: @jdweng I am able to connect and perform insert,delete and update operation. The issue is occurring during select statement only. I believe that driver is not causing the issue. Let me know if any of my understandings are wrong

Comment: The driver would be the reason for these type error.  A simple example would be if Oracle Updated a database to change features and updated driver for new version.  If you were still using the older driver you may get some errors.  When you are using drivers that are not Oracle this type problem would occur more often.

Comment: @jdweng I Tried without parameters I am able to perform select Operation

Comment: The datatype in c# must match the type defined in Oracle.  So either you are not defining the type correctly in c#, or the driver is not handling the datatype properly.